# Sci-fi short story: cloned alien-mind-controlled merc with human-body-mod dinosaur side-kick

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I've been looking for this story off and on for the past year, to no avail; I think it's pretty recent, published in the past 20 years or so. I read a lot of short story anthologies but I can't find this one.

The main character (a mercenary type) and side-kick (who IIRC is a human who's in the body of a dinosaur... maybe a velociraptor?) are enslaved by some sort of alien hive-mind who's using them to locate a powerful weapon.

They travel around in a stolen ship from some *other* alien race (IIRC caste-based, maybe crab-like?) that has a space-elevator they use to descend to planet surfaces and conduct deals in their effort to locate the weapon.

The story starts in media res, with the main character + side-kick in the middle of a deal gone bad (their trading partners were trying to rip them off and steal their ship; it doesn't end well for them).

The main character has to periodically contact the controlling hive-mind and endure agonizing psychic debriefings.

In the end (spoilers!) the main character finds the weapon and turns it against the hive-mind, and realizes he's a clone (the original was kept near the hive-mind in some sort of stasis chamber).

Anyway, I really loved the mood of this story and I'd like to reread it but I can't find it no matter how many Year's Best anthologies I scour!

Comment: This makes me think of Harry Harrison's [Bill, the Galactic Hero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill,_the_Galactic_Hero) but it's been a long time since I've read it. .

Comment: Thanks! Sadly that's not it (it was only a short story, and I'm pretty sure 2000s). But thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

FYI I eventually found the story: "The Other Gun" by Neal Asher

Comment: This is good to know, but you should [contact the mods](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/contact) and ask them to merge your accounts, so you can properly accept this.

Comment: If you follow the instructions [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) you can merge your accounts then you will be able to accept your own answer again from the account that asked this question!